# Can't Build wxWidgets on Cygwin with OpenGL Support

Tags: opengl, cygwin, wxwidgets

I am trying to build wxWidgets 2.8.11 under Cygwin, but the wxWidgets configure step is not generating OpenGL support.  Specifically, the build is not generating a library called libwx_mswd_gl-2.8.a.

I suspect that I am missing a Cygwin OpenGL package, but am not sure.  I already have the following OpenGL-related packages:  libglut-devel, libglut3, opengl, tiff-opengl.

Are there one or more packages that I still need, in order to add full openGL support?

Answer (score 1):

I've just stumbled on the same problem.
Configure is failing on GLU library so make sure that you have libGLU-devel installed:

```
$ cygcheck -cd libGLU-devel
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version
libGLU-devel         7.11.2-1
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Check your config.log to see what it's testing for OpenGL support.